# The series $\sum \frac{z^n}{n}$ converge $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}, |z|=1$ but not $z=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I see the answers using Abel's test, That is quite acceptable, but in my text book the hint is gives as "$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(k\theta)~\sum_{k=1}^n\sin(k\theta)  $ are bounded when $0<\theta<2\pi$"

I don't even understand whether the given hint is true and how to use it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can compute explicitly $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i k \theta}$.

Comment: Can u elaborate a bit?

Comment: It is contained in @JoséCarlosSantos ' answer. As $|z| = 1$, replace $z$ with $e^{i\theta}$ in the summation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to use Abel's test here. It is natural to use Dirichlet's test: if $N\in\mathbb N$, is $\lvert z\rvert=1$ and if $z\neq1$, then$$\left\lvert\sum_{n=1}^Nz^n\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{z-z^{N+1}}{1-z}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac2{\lvert z-1\rvert}.$$So, since $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ decreases and converges to $0$…

Comment: I am a beginner in complex analysis, I don't know about Dirichlet condition. Can it be solved by given hint?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't see how to use Abel's test? [This is literally the use case, isn't it?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel's_test_in_complex_analysis)

Comment: I don't see how.

Comment: From the link above: "Specifically, Abel's test states that if a sequence of positive real numbers $(a_n)_n$ is decreasing monotonically[...] with
$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =0$
then the power series
$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$
converges everywhere on the closed unit circle, except when $z = 1$."

Take $a_n = 1/n$.

Comment: @ClementC. What I had in mind was this theorem: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges and if $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a monotonic and convergent sequence of real numbers, then the series $\sum_{b=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I reckon that's the issue with Abel: he has too many results, and they have the same name.

Comment: See the statement of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: Can someone say how the hint helps the proof?

Comment: @MadhanKumar Take a look at the statement of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). Do you see the connection?

Comment: Oh ok thank you